# Getting the value from custom List

Tags: java

I have List name declared as public and person class have setter and getters methods.In service class has executed the method and it has list of values.

Now I want to get the all first name from list.

So try as below...

```
Iterator<Person> it = name.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) {

    name = (Person)it.next();
    String firsname=it.next();

}
```

Please correct me whats wrong here.

Comment: Is the list `name`?  Then, `name` can't be a `Person` too, so that line is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that code is not going to work, because your second cast is going to fail: `it.next()` will be a `Person`, not a `String`.

Here is how you can fix your code:

```
List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator <Person> it = name.iterator(); // shouldn't this be persons.iterator() ?
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Person p = it.next(); // No need to cast
    String firsname = p.getFirstName();
    firstNames.add(firstName);
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it like this:

```
List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Person p : persons) {
    firstNames.add(p.getFirstName());
}
```